# Condition before a for loop

Tags: python, loops

```
def uncompress(xs):
  zs = []
  b = True
  for k in xs:
  zs.extend([b for i in range(k)])
  b = not b
  return zs
```

Just wanted to know what having a variable or a condition before the for loop does in any case, so in this case what does 'b' for i in range do.

Comment: The `[b for i in range(k)]` isn't a loop, it's a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Answer (score 0):

Since `b = True`, `zs.extend([b for i in range(k)])` is effectively `zs.extend([True for i in range(k)])` or `zs.extend([True, True, ..., True (k times)])`.

Update. I'm assuming that the intended (indented) code is the following:

```
def uncompress(xs):
  zs = []
  b = True
  for k in xs:
    zs.extend([b for i in range(k)])
    b = not b
  return zs
```

Then if `xs` is, say, `[2, 1, 3]`, then:

- after the first for-loop execution (so called "iteration"), `zs = [] + [True, True] = [True, True]` and `b` becomes `False`,
- then `zs = [True, True] + [False] = [True, True, False]` and `b` becomes `True`,
- finally `zs = [True, True, False, True, True, True]` and `b` becomes `False`.

So if `xs == [s, t, u, v, ...]` then `zs` is `True` `s` times, `False` `t` times, `True` `u` times, `False` `v` times and so on.

Comment: Sorry, I'm extremely new to python so what would it do in a general sense, having that condition there?

Comment: I think I've asked a bad question I'm focused more on what 'b' is doing in a general sense not the line. @KirillBulygin

Comment: @JackJock It's just a variable, it contains a value. I think you need a basic introduction, see this: https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/introduction.html (for list comprehensions: https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=comprehension#list-comprehensions).